# Database returning different errors for same query. Instead of column name, column id is returning

Tags: php, mysql

I am very much annoyed with servers...

I have seen so many problems which didn't occurs on local system environment, and when the code is uploaded on server... everything seems to be against developers.

Problem :

On my local system I m using database error returned from mysql like :

```
  0 => string '23000' (length=5)
  1 => int 1062
  2 => string 'Duplicate entry 'xyzabc.com' for key 'domain'' (length=46)
```

and moulding error msg as my wish like:

```
string 'Error: xyzabc.com already exist/used.' (length=38)
```

for jquery flashing message as it didin't look good to display exactly same error returned by database.

X-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-X

Now when I uploaded on server to make it live it responded like this:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>  string(5) "23000"
[1]=>  int(1062) 
[2]=>  string(39) "Duplicate entry 'xyzabc.com' for key 2"
```

}

```
Field       Type                 Collation
id      int(11) 
domain      varchar(50)              latin1_swedish_ci
added       datetime    
is_delete   enum('no','yes')   latin1_swedish_ci
```

I can only use 1062 message,but I m posting multiple values, so for that I need to go through every posted value to check, that for which the error is coming.

Now where this key '2' came from?? :-/ as it should be domain. I am assuming that it is column_id. But how to solve this problem?? what I need to change in server to response like my local sytem environment?

Comment: first tell us your table structure

Comment: You will need to give us some more context here. Show us some code, schema or at least the query.

Comment: anything more is required????? i dont get y u start putitng down votes for a question, if it is incomplete :-)

Comment: Aakash has a point. At least give OPs a chance to correct their mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you have locally

```
  2 => string 'Duplicate entry 'xyzabc.com' for key 'domain'' (length=46)
```

and remotely

```
[2]=>  string(39) "Duplicate entry 'xyzabc.com' for key 2"
```

*NB Different quotes!*

Comment: no idea about that...as I am not an advanced user of mysql...but how to solve the problem??Is there settings to be changed on server mysql installation to work.